# changing css property relative to eq().. jQuery/JavaScript

Tags: jquery, html, css

i am trying to change the 'left' property of a group of divs dependant on their eq() value. i will show a basic code of what i'm trying to do! any help will be appreciated

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<div class"item-holder"></div>
  <div class"item item-one"></div>
  <div class"item item-one"></div>
  <div class"item item-one"></div>
  <div class"item item-one"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.item-holder {
position:relative;
width:100px;
}
.item {
position:absolute;
width:25px;
float:left;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(){
var itemWidth = $('.item-holder').width()/$('.item').size();
  $('.item').css({
    'left':$('.this').eq()*itemWidth+'px'
  });
};
```

please not this is not the full code i can post it if it makes more sense, the reason i need the left value to be created in jQuery is because i'd like to reuse this code in several different places and will use a different number of 'items' each time! any help is welcomed and taken onboard

Comment: So you have a class named "this"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `css` [function](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-functionindex-%20value).

> .css( propertyName, function(index, value) )

```
$('.item').css('left', function(ind, v){
    return (ind * itemWidth) + 'px'
})
```

Note that by using `$('.this')`, you are selecting elements with class of `this`, for creating a jQuery object from `this` object you should code `$(this)`.

Comment: ahh yes i knew that just a mistake a silly one at that! is function(ind, v){} a standard thing or are those parameters being created by me/you? thank you very much! also do you know which is the more proper or correct way of dealing with this? yours or @dystroy 's? thanks!

Comment: oops i just realised that was a really stupid question, my bad thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

What you seem to need is the [index](http://api.jquery.com/index/) :

```
$('.item').each(function(){
    $(this).css({
       'left':$(this).index()*itemWidth+'px'
    });
});
```

Note that you have a few errors in your code :

- you probably didn't want to close your first div and letting it empty
- when setting a class, don't forget the `=` operator

**[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/u28v8/)**

Comment: this worked thank you very much!! what is the difference between index and eq? and what do you mean by the = operator?

Comment: [eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) gives you a collection reduced to the element at the index you pass while [index](http://api.jquery.com/index/) gives you the index.